# can i use google code for a open source SaaS software for which code is not being distributed to any one?

Tags: google-code

I wanted to know, I have a SaaS(Software-as-a-service) product that is open source... I dont distribute the source code to anyone.

Can i use google code and create a new project for this software. I want to use the Bug Tracker functionality.

I want to use Google Code without distributing the source code of my software to any one.

Comment: You have a very strange definition of "open source".

Comment: If you're not distributing the source code, then it's not open source. If it's not open source, then you can't host it on Google Code. Could you elaborate on why you think this is open source?

Comment: this discrepancy is there because the GPL license considers only software applications that are distributed-- only the AGPL deals with the scenario of Software-as-a-service-

Comment: @Arvind I think I understand what you're saying but you still have to allow users to download your source code in order to be considered some form of open source. What license is your source code under?

Comment: IANAL, but it sounds like your sofware is merely complying with GPL, not that it's open source itself.

Comment: i am signing up for a fogbugz account (for startups)... i also wrote in to git hub explaining my scenario but no reply from them... so far...@Juhana- what you are saying is correct, i did nt think of it that way until you pointed it out...

Answer (score 0):

Per http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/FAQ#Hosting_Your_Open_Source_Project_on_Google_Code

As long is it's open source and you're in a country where google conducts business--you're in luck.